# how i can create a filename start with "

Tags: scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am looking to create a file with this name:

```
"\?$*'Helloword'*$?\"
```

I was trying with this command but the result not correctly

```
touch \"\\\?\$\*\'\Helloword\'\*\$\?\\\"
```

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: "I am looking to create a file with this name" --- Why?!?!  Drunk nerd dare?  Homework assignment from psychotic professor out to drive his students equally insane with quoting/escaping rules?  Just ... why? ;-)

Comment: We do really need to know why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which shell, but I'll assume `bash`. Well then, Congratulations!  The quoted/escaped string you are using is actually **correct**.

So why did you think it was wrong?  You didn't show your output or how you retrieved it, but I'm also going to assume that you used `ls` (it's only natural).

`ls` is returning `'"\?$*'\''Helloword'\''*$?\"'`.  But that's actually just another quoted/escaped form of what you are asking for, `"\?$*'Helloword'*$?\"`.

Want/need proof?

First, do another `touch`, but this time using the form that `ls` is showing you:

```
touch '"\?$*'\''Helloword'\''*$?\"'
```

Now do another `ls`.  Still only the one file there, right?

`'"\?$*'\''Helloword'\''*$?\"'` == `"\?$*'Helloword'*$?\"`

Further, `exa`, a modern replacement for `ls` written in Rust, does return the form you started with:

```
> exa -l \"*
.rw-r--r-- 0 username 30 Apr  1:35 "\?$*'Helloword'*$?\"
```

But you don't need to install `exa` to see that.  A much more basic `ls` replacement can be had with:

```
> echo \"*
"\?$*'Helloword'*$?\"
```

Side note:

I sometimes find it easier to build up complicated quoting/escaping cases step-by-step.  For instance:

```
> filename=Helloword
> filename="'$filename'"
> filename=\*$filename\*
> filename=\$$filename\$
> filename=\?$filename\?
> filename=\\$filename\\
> filename=\"$filename\"
> echo $filename
"\?$*'Helloword'*$?\"
> touch $filename
```

Of course, you can `echo` the variable at any stage to make sure you are on the right track.

Comment: You don't need to go to `exa` or `echo` for that, `ls --quoting-style=literal` is enough.

Comment: Thank you!  So many options ...

Comment: Thank you so  much for the clarification